# Run a process and get the result in clipboard (or kill ring) with elisp/emacs

Tags: elisp

I use the following code to run "ls -l ./" and get the result in *scratch* buffer.

```
(start-process "my-process" "*scratch*" "ls" "-l" "./")
```

- How can I get the result in clipboard or something (kill ring or whatever) so that I can easily copy the result whenever necessary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can adjust this to your liking:

```
(kill-new (shell-command-to-string "ls -l ."))
```

The call to `kill-new` will put the string from `shell-command-to-string` on the kill ring.

Answer (score 2):

`shell-command` (bound to M-!) runs a shell command and puts its output in `*Shell Command Output*`. Given an argument (eg: M-1 M-!) it will put the results in the current buffer.

A little more information is available on the page [ExecuteExternalCommand](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ExecuteExternalCommand) on the Emacs wiki

Comment: Whereupon it is immediately kill-able. So `C-u M-! (command) RET C-w` gets the results into the kill ring. And you can use the minibuffer's history (`C-p` or up arrow) to easily re-enter recent commands without re-typing them.